# KeyPress event doesn't print last entered character

Tags: vba, excel, ascii

When printing the characters entered on a textbox the last one is always omitted. Tried with KeyUp event but it triggers the  Case Else on every input. Any idea?

```
Private Sub hoursOverBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
    Case 46, 48 To 57
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
        MsgBox "Only numbers allowed!"
End Select
Me.hoursOverBox.MaxLength = 5
On Error Resume Next
hoursOver = Me.hoursOverBox.value
End Sub
```

Comment: Try the `KeyDown` event.

Comment: @RyanWildry it doesn't work either.

Comment: If you are trying to capture the value after it's typed. Use the `Change` Event.

Comment: I did it with a Change event before, but I still would like to give a try to the above one as with the Change event I'll have to add way more code in order to limit the input to certain characters.

Comment: You'll need both events. One to prevent certain characters, and another to capture the value. IIRC, the value doesn't update until after the change event. You could always add a button or something to grab the value on press.

Comment: That works indeed. A bit messy if I continue increasing the number of InputBoxes I have, but does what I want. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger
```

to

```
ByVal KeyAscii As Integer
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be valid. Gives a compile error.

Comment: I tried your code in Excel 2016 - works perfectly. Not sure what are you trying to achieve? A textbox allowing only numbers, am I right?

Comment: that's correct, but as I explain above it dismisses the last entered character. I'm using Excel 2013, perhaps the reason?

Comment: Weird... I cannot reproduce this behavior, seems to work correctly. I have a textbox with MaxLength=0 and MultiLine=False. Excel 2013 should also work correctly. Can you try this: create another textbox and don't alter the properties in any way. Add the code above in KeyPress and see  the result.

Comment: I tried it a few times. I have more TextBoxes and the same applies for all of them.  I modified the MaxLength to the need of each TextBox, but I suppose that shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, even though probably not the cleaner solution, I implemented what Ryan proposed above and it's working OK. I'm using a Keypress and Change events for each TextBox.